# KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /kafka-manager/mutex

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, yahoo-kafka-manager

The following error is being prompted when it is tried to add a new cluster in 'CMAK' in the K8s cluster.

```
Yikes! KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /kafka-manager/mutex Try again.
```

My cluster configurations are as follows,

```
zookeeper: wurstmeister/zookeeper
kafka-manager: kafkamanager/kafka-manager:3.0.0.4
kafka: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.4.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could resolve it by following the steps.

1. Connect to the 'zookeeper' container in k8s

   k exec -it podid -- bash
2. Connect with zookeeper cli,

   ./bin/zkCli.sh
3. Make sure that it has created the 'kafka-manager' path already. if it does not exist, then try to create a cluster in 'kafka-manager' first.

   ls /kafka-manager
4. Hit the following commands to create subsequent paths,

   create /kafka-manager/mutex ""

   create /kafka-manager/mutex/locks ""

   create /kafka-manager/mutex/leases ""
5. Now try to create the cluster again.

The output would be like this,

```
WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /kafka-manager
[configs, deleteClusters, clusters]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] create /kafka-manager/mutex ""
Created /kafka-manager/mutex
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] create /kafka-manager/mutex/locks ""
Created /kafka-manager/mutex/locks
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 3] create /kafka-manager/mutex/leases ""
Created /kafka-manager/mutex/leases
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 4]
```

The original answer is mentioned here,
https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK/issues/731#issuecomment-643880544

Comment: I'm not using docker, where I need to execute those commands ?

Comment: If you could find zkcli.Sh under /bin/zkCli.sh, then the other steps would be the same.